# Ubuntu 18 - remote access with Windows / Multi-user

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have a small desktop computer on which I have installed Ubuntu 18. My goal is to operate this pc from my main computer running under Windows 10.

I have configured a VNC server in command line to make it start automatically and I can access it from my Windows PC through Putty. So far, so good but now I'd like to see the Ubuntu desktop instead of using SSH and I'd like to control the computer while another user is using the machine.

Question 1:
How can I control the Ubuntu desktop from my Windows PC ? I tried to connect with my VNC client but the connection is refused.

I can see the desktop only if I start the X11VNC server app but that app doesn't start automatically.

Question 2:
There is a second user on this machine, if this second user is actively using the Ubuntu computer, I only get a black screen. Is there a way to access the desktop (visually) while someone else is using the same machine but with a different user?

Thanks!

Laurent

Comment: Have you tried turning on **Settings > Sharing > Screen Sharing?** You will need to be logged on locally first and stay logged on. Then you will be able to share the screen and "control the screen" from your remote computer using VNC.

Comment: @user68186 Yes I have enable screen sharing from the settings. I'm sorry about the title, you're right, I'm looking for remote access and not remove access :)